# « Grammaire française » et « grammaire du français »

Tags: grammaire, usage

Les livres de grammaire destinés aux francophones portent tantôt le titre
**Grammaire du français** tantôt **Grammaire française**.

Y a-t-il des différences (contenu, approches, niveau, etc.) entre les différents genres ? Par ailleurs, quelques fois que j'avais utilisé la tournure **grammaire du français** dans les questions/réponses au sein de FSE celle-ci a été modifiée à **grammaire française**. Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une *grammaire française* est un ouvrage de référence qui s'adresse à des personnes connaissant déjà bien le français alors qu'un *grammaire du français*,  [plus rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grammaire%20fran%C3%A7aise%2Cgrammaire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1780&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgrammaire%20fran%C3%A7aise%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrammaire%20fran%C3%A7aise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrammaire%20fran%C3%A7aise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrammaire%20Fran%C3%A7aise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGRAMMAIRE%20FRAN%C3%87AISE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgrammaire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrammaire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrammaire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrammaire%20du%20Fran%C3%A7ais%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGRAMMAIRE%20DU%20FRAN%C3%87AIS%3B%2Cc0), indique plutôt un ouvrage destiné à des non francophones.

On peut donc dire qu'une grammaire française enseigne la grammaire tandis qu'une grammaire du français enseigne aussi le français.

Les modifications apportées aux questions-réponses sur FSE sont certainement dues à des Français ayant toujours été en contact avec des *grammaires françaises* lors de leur scolarité et jamais avec des *grammaires du français*.

[image: Google NGram]

Référence: https://journals.openedition.org/dhfles/1277